# Select default value from GET value

Tags: php, select, html-select

My website is using form editing to click on a record, which then opens up a form and allows for all of the values to be edited, and saved to append the new values. However the issue I am facing is the select, which should be using the default value from $_GET, but instead the default is coming up as the value which is first in alphabetical order, not what it should actually be. So the issue is if i edit and save, the form is automatically placing the wrong value within the select box.

The code I am using for my select is as follows:

```
echo "<select name='ClientCode'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option  value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'>" . $row['ClientName'] ."</option>";}
    echo "</select><br>";   //CLOSE DROP DOWN BOX
```

How can I edit the above snippet to allow my $cli = $_GET["ClientCode"] to be shown within the select box as the default value on page load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your while loop like :

```
$cli = isset($_GET["ClientCode"])?$_GET["ClientCode"]:"";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $selected =  ($cli == $row['ClientCode']) ? "selected" : "";
    echo "<option  value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."' $selected >" . $row['ClientName'] ."</option>";}
```

Comment: B.Desai, thank you. I will accept yours as the answer as (1) worked without an issue. 2) very simplistic as oppose to what I had in mind, and others below which still worked but double in no. of lines and complexity

Answer (score 3):

Change your `<select ...> ... <select>` dropdown list code in the following way,

```
echo "<select name='ClientCode'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output = "<option  value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'";
    if(isset($_GET["ClientCode"]) && $row['ClientCode'] == $_GET["ClientCode"]){
        $output .= " selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= ">" . $row['ClientName'] ."</option>";
    echo $output;
}
echo "</select><br>";
```

Comment: @Dimash As per OP's question, `$_GET["ClientCode"]` shall exist. However, I do agree with your point, hence added an additional check there.

Comment: Sure but I advice always do request checks and set default values, otherwise could be problems.  It is more important what will work better empty or isset

Comment: @Dimash No, we don't need any default value here. The control won't go further, and inside the `if` block, if either `$_GET["ClientCode"]` is not set or it's not equal to the current `$row['ClientCode']`. So it won't cause any issue there.

Comment: @Dimash That's not correct. If the URL is *example.com/index.php?x*, then `var_dump(isset($_GET['y']));` would simply return `false`. Check this first.

Answer (score 0):

You need check $_GET in your loop and do selected="selected" for needed option

```
echo "<select name='ClientCode'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!empty($_GET["ClientCode") && $_GET["CleintCode"] == $row["ClientCode"]))
    {
     echo "<option  selected='selected' value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'>" . $row['ClientName'] ."
    </option>";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<option  value='" . $row['ClientCode'] ."'>" . $row['ClientName'] ."
</option>";
     }
}
echo "</select><br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```php
if($row['ClientCode'] == $_GET["ClientCode"])
{
?>
    <option selected="selected">
    Value goes here...
    </option>
<?php
}
```